# Problem with tick mark position

Tags: plotting, ticks

I am plotting this piecewise function:

$$\rho (x,0) = \rho_{max} \text{  if } x \leq 0 $$ $$\rho (x,0) = 0 \text{  if } x>0. $$

I used this code

```
Plot[Piecewise[{{pmax, x <= 0}, {0, x > 0}}], {x, -2000, 2000}, 
 Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "\[Rho]"}, 
 Ticks -> {{0}, {{2000, "pmax"}}}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01]]
```

and I get this:

[image]

Is it possible to move the tick label $\rho_{max}$ to the right?

Comment: Yeah. Look at the examples for `Ticks` in `Plot`.

Comment: You have a syntax error (extra comma).

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Thanks, but that was a mistake I made copying. My original code was fine.

Comment: Also... don't you need to specify `pmax = 2000`?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Sorry, I forgot to copy it because in the nb is separeted somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [`Epilog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog) instead of trying to hack the [`Ticks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks) option to move the tick label to the right:

```
Plot[
    Piecewise[{{2000, x<=0}, {0, x > 0}}],
    {x, -2000, 2000},
    Axes->True, AxesLabel->{"x","\[Rho]"},
    Ticks->None, Epilog->Text["pmax", Offset[{20, 0}, {0,2000}]],
    PlotStyle->Thickness[0.01]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!!!